# Lista acumuladora python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursão, iterator

Estou a desenvolver uma função que receba 3 parâmetros fctn(function, list, element)
e que tem de devolver  uma lista com os estados intermédios do acumulador, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
>>> fctn(lambda acc, x: acc + x, [1, 2, 3, 4], 0) 
[0, 1, 3, 5,7]
```

Meu código:

```
def fctn(function, list, element):

acc = elem

for x in list: 
    list = map(lambda acc: lambda x: acc + x, l)

return list
```

Mas não devolve o que eu pretendo...

Comment: Está um pouco confusa a pergunta, tente demonstrar atraves de uma função comum (sem lambda) ou mesmo atraves de pseudocodigo ou teste de mesa.

Comment: Cara... Entendi. É praticamente a mesma pergunta que respondi algumas horas atras. Refatorei o codigo para atender essa sua questão.

Comment: por favor, poste código coma  identação correta

Comment: @py_9,  De acordo com o teu texto, para ser um acumulador  com `lambda acc, x: acc + x` não deveria dar a lista das soma acumulada `[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja se atende:

```
import functools

# Utilizando Funcoes de alta ordem
def acumulator(n,dt):
    current = n+dt['last']
    dt['ac'].append(current)
    dt['last'] = n

data = {'last': 0, 'ac': []}
list(map(lambda n: acumulator(n, data), [n for n in range(0,5)]))

print ('Acumuladores => ',data['ac'])
Acumuladores =>  [0, 1, 3, 5, 7]
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/HC41/6)

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com o enunciado, eu esperava um resultado diferente: a lista das somas acumuladas parciais.

Sugeria uma definição recursiva:

```
def fctn(f,l,n):
  if not l: 
     return [n]
  else: 
     return [n]+fctn(f,l[1:], f(n,l[0]))
```

ou seja:

```
>>> fctn(lambda acc, x: acc + x, [1, 2, 3, 4], 0)
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```